# Is there an error in my 'Hide Sheet' Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

This only works and hides the Sheet 'Finances' when I am an admin and a user, I want Admins to have access to the sheet and non admin uses to have it hidden. I'm not entirely sure if this is even possible using one customer script or not, but if so tell me what i am doing wrong.

This is something that i have been working for the last 3 weeks, I am new to google scripts so any help will be appreciated, but I am by no means an expert, but in theory this works.

```js
function onOpen() {
  var adminUsers = ['maiceo@******.com','nick@*****.com','ash@******.com','justinp@*****.com'];
  var Users = ['lorit@*****.com','zachp@******.com','devonc@******.com','rileev@*****.com','maiceoh@*******.com'];

  if (adminUsers.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Finances').showSheet()
  }

  if (Users.indexOf(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()) >= 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Finances').hideSheet()
  }
}
```

I expected admiUsers to have viewing abilities and users not to, but it is either all or nothing. I want it to work like keycard authorization when you open the doc.

Comment: Do all users have edit permissions or just view permissions?

Comment: To various degrees they do, but as far as the sheet I am looking to hide no, only admins would have edit access.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*In order to have a trigger run by a user, they need to have edit access to the Sheet.*

#### More Information:

As per the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started) , only users with edit access can run triggers that are bound to a Google Sheet:

> onOpen(e) runs when a user opens a spreadsheet, document, presentation, or form that the user has permission to edit.

You would need to require all users to have edit permissions to be able to do this.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

  - [Getting Started with Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started)